# Machine Learning to draw a topology of elements

Tags: machine-learning, network-topology, topology, graph-drawing

I'm exploring the idea of using machine learning to draw a topology of elements. For example, imagine a tree representing geological hierarchy (country -> province -> city). All countries are at the top-most level, then the provinces for each country, followed by the provinces splitting into cities at the 3rd vertical level.

The vertical positions of the elements are trivial to compute:

- Country ->  0 %
- Province -> 33%
- City -> 66%

in a canvas going vertically down as the % increases.

However, I'm having trouble thinking of how to format the data to determine the horizontal position. I'm aware that there are non-ml algorithms to draw topologies, but I'm exploring this as a proof of concept.

My plan right now is to assign each element **id,parentId,rank** properties where

- id is a unique id
- parentId is the id of the parent element
- rank is 1/2/3

However, I feel like this isn't the best way to represent the data to feed into the ml model.
I'm welcome to any guidance/recommendations on how to better represent the problem.

[image: My terrible mspaint description of the problem:]

Comment: I think your post a sub-optimal fit for a Q&A-site: [Real Questions Have Answers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you have a real problem you're trying to solve, then the requirement to restrict yourself to ML seems artificial and unhelpful.  ML isn't magic and isn't appropriate for all problems.  I don't see a specific question in your post. We're looking for narrowly focused, technical questions.